# which type of notification should be used local notification or push notification?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, cordova, notifications

I'm developing a communication app using Phonegap framework wherein the concept of notification has just came into picture. The app should notify the end user about the new message/event occurring in the app.

1) So my question is for these kind of notifications which type of notifications should be used is it local ? or is it remote/push ?. I came across local notification plugins for phonegap and at the same time i even went through parse.com but confused in what to use.

2)Another question which is running across my mind is for push notifications we need to generate APN's (Apple Push Notification certificate), do we need to generate APN certificate for local notifications as well...?

Please do the needful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. So my question is for these kind of notifications which type of notifications should be used is it local ? or is it remote/push?**

As your backend needs to notify to the user when a new message/event occurs, so you will have to use remote notifications (Push notifications)

**2. Do we need to generate APN certificate for local notifications as well...?**

No we don't need, generating APNS certificate is only required for remote notifications in iOS

Answer (score 0):

> "I came across local notification plugins for phonegap and at the
>   same time i even went through parse.com but confused in what to use.".

Push Notification is the best way for a communication app like all the notifications i get from my Facebook app that's push notification.

So you can write a script that notifies your users for new updates.

> "do we need to generate APN certificate for local notifications as
>   well...?"

No you don't... Local Notifications are offline reminders e.g for scheduling an appointment or an alarm (Which you don't need internet for).